# jquery : dynamically alert while user changes size of browser

Tags: jquery, image, browser, dynamic, resize

If a user resizes a browser I want to display an alert. What I'm trying to do is change the users image width/height with jQuery. When the user resizes the browser, the image will be resized dynamically. So if someone can show me how to do it with `alert`, I think I can try to figure out the rest.

Right now I know how to get the user's current browser height and width, but it will only `alert` on load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var docWidth = $(document).width();
    alert(docWidth);
});
```

So this will give user's docWidth when browser opens.

Also, if someone has time to explain the difference between window and document width's and height. I tried both scenarios and its giving me the same information.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `window`'s `resize` event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    //run code on window resize
});
```

[See the API reference](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)